# What's the sql alternative for a for loop in python?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop

I have a table in sql with `cp` and `cid` as two columns of the many in it. `a, av, b, bv, c, cv` are strings in the column and `17, 18` are in column cid.

```
for cp in ['a', 'av', 'b', 'bv', 'c', 'cv']:
  for cid in [17,18]:
    df= get_dataframes(cp,cid)
    ccl = str(cid)
    pickle_name = "ccmp/_" + ccl + "_"+ cp + "_recent.pkl"

    result_df = pd.Dataframe(df)
```

I have 2 for loop's like ^ in python. I need to replicate them in SQL. I'm not sure how to use the while loop to do this since sql doesn't have a direct alternative to for loop in python. I'm using MS SQL Server. I ONLY WANT TO REPLICATE THE FOR LOOP. Not everything my python script does, it is only a sample where i used my for loop. Apologies for any confusion.

`get_dataframes` is a function to get dataframes from a bunch of other dataframes after filtering with `cp`  and `cid`. What the for loop does is runs the function for all the combinations of `cp`  and `cid`  and stores them into the pickles.

All i need the sql for loop to do is be able to give me the different combinations for `cp` and `cid` i get from my python loop.

The loop will have a select statement that gives 2 records of each combination from the 100's of records i have for every combination i.e (a, 17) (a,18) (av,17) (av,18) . . .

What my sql essentially should do is take the below table, run the loop on it

```
x    y    cp    cid
aaa  bbb  a      22
aaa  bbb  a      27
aaa  bbb  a      17
aaa  bbb  av     17
aaa  bbb  b      22
aaa  bbb  b      18
aaa  bbb  bv     18
aaa  bbb  c      22
aaa  bbb  cv     18
aaa  bbb  c      17
aaa  bbb  d      17
aaa  bbb  dv     18
aaa  bbb  j      17
aaa  bbb  a      22
aaa  bbb  a      27
aaa  bbb  a      17
aaa  bbb  av     17
aaa  bbb  b      22
aaa  bbb  b      18
aaa  bbb  bv     18
aaa  bbb  c      22
aaa  bbb  cv     18
aaa  bbb  c      17
aaa  bbb  d      17
aaa  bbb  dv     18
aaa  bbb  j      17
```

and get a final view that looks like

```
x    y    cp    cid
aaa  bbb  a      17
aaa  bbb  a      17
aaa  bbb  av     17
aaa  bbb  av     17
aaa  bbb  b      18
aaa  bbb  b      18
aaa  bbb  bv     18
aaa  bbb  bv     18
aaa  bbb  c      17
aaa  bbb  c      17
aaa  bbb  cv     18
aaa  bbb  cv     18
```

Comment: What does the loop do? If you explain that you will probably get better answers from the people who don't know Python (like me :))

Comment: @JacobH I edited my question. I hope that helps. Happy to give more clarity if needed. Thank you :)

Comment: So you need all possible combinations of one `cp` and one `cid`? A `CROSS JOIN` will do that for you. Short on time else I'd post an answer.

Comment: Thanks @alroc, but that's not what i was looking for. I edited my question with more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the loop does. SQL treats data as sets, but you can conceptualise it as there being some operations that loop over the data and carry out functions. If your loops here calculate some totals, averages or other single value aggregates of multiple individual values on your data, in SQL that would be a GROUP BY together with some aggregating function like AVG, SUM etc. If your loops in python produce a list of strings by concatenation variable and fixed strings, then that's just a simple select statement with the relevant concatenation commands. If your loop in python does...

So you can see that for targeted advice and example queries you're really going to have to show us the block of data hat goes into your loops and what comes out. And it it's not obvious wha transforms are applied to get from start to finish, they'll need describing too

Edit: based on what you've described your loops to do.. sql processes blocks of existing data. If you're after an sql that invents data, you really have to put the data into the select statement. Your cp and cid might hence be represented like this:

```
Select concat(a.cp,b.cid) from
(Select 'a' as cp union all select 'av' union all select 'b' ...) a
Cross join
(Select '17' as cid union all select '18') b
```

The result of his sql will be 12 rows of every combination of cp and cid. I passed them into the concat command to demonstrate this, but you might want to pass them into a command that makes pickles. Or chutneys.

Comment: Thanks for the assist

Comment: Thank you @caius, I edited my question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
Select pickle_name = concat('ccmp/_' , cid , '_' , cp ,'_recent.pkl')
 From (values ('a'),('av'),('b'),('bv'),('c'),('cv') ) A(cp)
 Cross Join (Select * from (values (17),(18)) B(cid)) B
```

Return

```
pickle_name
ccmp/_17_a_recent.pkl
ccmp/_17_av_recent.pkl
ccmp/_17_b_recent.pkl
ccmp/_17_bv_recent.pkl
ccmp/_17_c_recent.pkl
ccmp/_17_cv_recent.pkl
ccmp/_18_a_recent.pkl
ccmp/_18_av_recent.pkl
ccmp/_18_b_recent.pkl
ccmp/_18_bv_recent.pkl
ccmp/_18_c_recent.pkl
ccmp/_18_cv_recent.pkl
```

Comment: Thanks, but i won't be reading my pickles. I just need to replicate the python code in sql.

Comment: You can't, or you can, it depends what you mean by replicate. What john wrote here is correct in that your python code makes a list of pickle names and so does his sql. His sql doesn't use loops that you can see, so it may not meet with your understanding of 'replicate' but that's because asking sql to work like python does is like asking a fish to drive a submarine

Comment: @beginnerdscientist The results can be incorporated into a CROSS APPLY or JOIN.  Not clear your desired results / end-game

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, this can be done with a straightforward SELECT.

Try the following:

```
declare @test table
(
x char(3),
y char(3),
cp varchar(2),
cid int
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      22),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      27),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'av',     17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'b',      22),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'b',      18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'bv',     18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'c',      22),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'cv',     18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'c',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'd',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'dv',     18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'j',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      22),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      27),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'a',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'av',     17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'b',      22),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'b',      18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'bv',     18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'c',      22),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'cv',     18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'c',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'd',      17),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'dv',     18),
('aaa',  'bbb',  'j',      17)

;WITH  cte as
(SELECT x,y,cp,cid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x,y,cp,cid 
ORDER BY x,y,cp,cid) as row_num
 FROM @test WHERE cp IN('a','av','b','bv','c', 'cv')
AND cid IN (17,18))
SELECT x,y,cp,cid FROM cte WHERE row_num < 3
```

This gives a result set of:

```
aaa bbb a   17
aaa bbb a   17
aaa bbb av  17
aaa bbb av  17
aaa bbb b   18
aaa bbb b   18
aaa bbb bv  18
aaa bbb bv  18
aaa bbb c   17
aaa bbb c   17
aaa bbb cv  18
aaa bbb cv  18
```

EDIT

You will need to do a little bit of performance checking on your data.  Obviously, you could just alter my original post by changing < 3 into < 501.

The alternative which may be faster would be to use a count and then to generate the result set according to the count.  Have the same first declare and insert as above but then go:

```
declare @test2 table
(
RecCount int,
x char(3),
y char(3),
cp varchar(2),
cid int
)

INSERT INTO @test2
SELECT COUNT(*) as RecCount, x, y, cp, cid FROM @test
WHERE cp IN('a','av','b','bv','c', 'cv')
AND cid IN (17,18)
GROUP BY x, y, cp, cid

declare @cnt int = 1
declare @insertcnt int

declare @x char(3)
declare @y char(3)
declare @cp varchar(2)
declare @cid int
declare @rc int

declare @results table
(
x char(3),
y char(3),
cp varchar(2),
cid int
)

DECLARE cur CURSOR 
FOR SELECT x, y, cp, cid, CASE WHEN RecCount < 2 THEN RecCount ELSE 2 END FROM @test2

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @x, @y, @cp, @cid, @rc

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @insertcnt = 0 
        WHILE @insertcnt < @rc
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @results VALUES(@x, @y, @cp, @cid)
            SET @insertcnt = @insertcnt + 1
        END
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur
        INTO @x, @y, @cp, @cid, @rc
    END

SELECT * FROM @results
```

Normally using a cursor is slow, but here we know there will only be 12 records (at most), so it will be quick.  That means the only thing to check is whether doing a grouped count with two INs and then generating data is quicker than the Partition BY approach with a select depending on row_number.

Clearly you will need to replace the 2 in the CASE statement with 500 (or possibly with a parameter??)

Comment: Hi Jonathan , So if i have 10 records like the first one, it'll show all of them. But i need only 2 records of each combination . . Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the code to restrict each line to a maximum of two records.  I was not sure what each combination meant - I have assumed it means combination of all four fields, but if it is less than four, you should be able to see how to change the PARTITION BY to less fields.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan , I think this should work. But my table has a couple million records and I need around 500 records of each cp and cid combination. You think it is still ideal to do it this way?

Comment: You are starting to lose me here. Do. you just want to generate 500 records of particular combinations which you know in advance or do you want to select records that match particular criteria?

Comment: I want to select records that match my criteria. My final view would be 500 records with cp & cid as as,17 another 500 with cp & cid as av, 17 another 500 with cp & cid as a, 18 another 500 with cp & cid as av, 18 . . .

Comment: Is this provided 500 of each do exist as rows in the table?  For example, if the table only has 450 'aaa', 'bbb', 'a', 17 do you still want 500, or just 450?

Comment: Yes, that is provided there are 500 rows exists. If only 450 exist, I'll take the 450.